# how use windows authentication from an outside domain client machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, windows-authentication, membership-provider

I'm developing a web MVC 4 application with Visualstudio 2013

I'm stuck in a issue, web application should use Windows Authentication in a intranet environment. Enabling the right options on IIS express it works fine . (web page shows the logged user)

the problems come when a client, that is not joined into the domain (like the developer machine), tries to use that web application. even if the client insert the right credentials into the popup, authentication keeps fail

Into the webconfig I have the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider an connectionstring set... maybe is not enough

so, what is the best practice / right configuration to allow this scenario?
any help is appreciated

Comment: When you input credentials, are you including a domain name? `MYDOMAIN\localuser` for example.

Comment: yes sure, myDomain\ADuser, but I can't understand if it make query on ldap server...

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

- Entering domain\username and password should work. If it doesn't something it wrong server-side.
- In IIS Manager, open the authentication options for that application, right-click 'Windows Authentication' and click 'Providers'. You'll probably see "Negotiate" and "NTLM". If so, try removing "Negotiate" and try again. If it works, that means there is an issue with the Kerberos setup for that site. You can then troubleshoot that.
- Are there any authentication settings in the application itself that disallows certain users from logging in? It's possible that it authenticates properly, but the application does not allow that user.